# JQuery,Passing Form POST/FILES data to PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have simple Image ulpoad HTML Form, The Idea is, I'm passing my Data to PHP script Via JQuery, Anyway, My script is not passing $_FILES Data
Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#addpic').live('submit', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.post('add.php', $(this).serialize(), function (data, textStatus) {
                    if (data == "true") { //Upload successful
                        $('#submitf').hide();
                        $('#backf').hide();

                        var thank="<br><br><br><center><h3>Teşekkürler,<br>fotoğraf kontrol edildikten sonra aktif hale gelecektir.</h3></center><br><br><br>";
                        $('#signupdiv').html(thank);
                    }
                    else if (data == "err") {

                    }
                     else {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
</script>
```

and For Sure my Form is

```
<form method="POST" action="" name="addpic" id="addpic" onsubmit="return checkform(this);"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

and PHP is simple no problem in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without full HTML5 support, you cannot effectively upload files using pure AJAX. There are ways to cheat, however...

I answered a very similar question a while back with a little trick I use for non-HTML5 browsers (IE7 and 8) in order to get a file upload going. It is pretty lightweight and dependencies are light: requires one iframe, and JS.

The drawback: no statuscode checks are possible.

More info on this answer link:

[Can I use JavaScript/JQuery to add an uploaded file to Request.Files in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570983/can-i-use-javascript-jquery-to-add-an-uploaded-file-to-request-files-in-asp-net/13573003#13573003)

Answer (score 0):

You can't upload files using jquery ajax. You can use some available jquery file upload plugins like http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

Google it to get more plugins and use which ever suited with your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to search anywhere `jQuery.form` plugin will do the trick for you.

See http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload